# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null on line 27

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Can't seem to insert sign-up data to a localhost database. I am using XAMP. I am trying to build a login system. I already created the form now I am trying to use SQL to insert data. I keep getting an error. I have researched online to no avail.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null on line 27

```
<?Php

require "config.php";


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $errMsg = '';

    $userid=$_POST['userid'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $password2=$_POST['password2'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
}

try {

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  mem_signup (userid,password,email) VALUES (?, ?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['userid'], $_POST['password'],$_POST['email'] ) ;
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
    exit;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined') {
    $errMsg = 'Registration successfull. Now you can <a href="login.php">login</a>';
}
?>
```

config.php

```
     <?php
    function dataConnect() {
    global $dbo;



    $info['dbhost_name'] = "localhost";
    $info['database'] = "mem-mgmt-v1";
    $info['username'] = "root";
    $info['password'] = "";


    $dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . $info['dbhost_name'] . "; dbname=" .                          $info['database'];

     $dbo = new PDO($dbConnString, $info['username'], $info['password']);
     $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
     $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $error = $dbo->errorInfo();
    if($error[0] != "") {

     }
```

}

?>

Comment: I didn't see where you define the mysqli connection? is it in `config.php`?

Comment: Yes it is in config.php.

Comment: Can you show us the code in `config.php`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the define part of your question. I will look up on how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the system here... Do I suppose to paste my code in the answer section?

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom of your post, you can edit your question there. Answer section is for **answers** only.

Comment: OK. I am going to place the code there. Thanks.

Comment: Updated and Define connection. It says connection successful but still error...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Comment: 1) your connection is named `$dbo` while you use `$mysqli` to perform the query. 2) your connection object is a PDO object, but the way you perform prepare query is mysqli style, choose one only and stick with that.